# Origin of the expressionTalmide Tarbitsae

Tags: talmud-gemara, rashi

Rashi in Yoma 62b, when he refute a version of the text of the Gemara calls it Shitata Detalmide Tarbitsae.

> ומוספין של שבת - שנאמר בהם שני כבשים ודאי שנים שוים לעיכובא מדלא הדר כתב בהו אחד לרבות אע"פ שאינן שוין להכשיר כך שמעתי וקשיא לי עיכובא מנלן ונראה בעיני דהכי גרס מוספין ודאי שנים למצוה מצותן להיות שוין ולא גרסי' מדלא כתיב אחד אחד ושיטתא דתלמידי תרביצאי היא

When searching in Sefaria, I found similarly Girsa Detalmide Tarbitsae. It seems to be Girsa from bad students. In Sefer Haruch on the word Tarbats, one of the meaning o Tarbitsa is Beth Midrash. The expression "Detalmide Tarbitsae" about a wrong is often used in Poskim. Some books seems to think that they are scholars after the Savorayim period. If it is the case, why are them reported only when they adds are viewed as false. Is someone able to explain consistently this expression.